# How do I perform this type of cartesian product in spark 2.01

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, cartesian-product

**// I'm using Spark 2.01 //**

And my data looks like,

```
(K1,Array(V1,V2,V3.....V30))
(K2,Array(V1,V2,V3.....V30))
(K3,Array(V1,V2,V3.....V30))
...
(K3704, Array(V1,V2,V3.....V30))
```

and I want to create a cartesian product list value for each key's value.

```
(K1, (V1,V2),(V1,V3),(V1,V4) ...
(K2, (V2,V3),(V2,V4),(V2,V5) ...
...
//PS. there are no duplicate elements like (V1,V2) == (V2,V1)
```

And I think there will be a 30! Operation for each key, but it would be better if it could be optimized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python we can use `combinations()` function from the package `itertools` inside `mapValues()`:

```py
from itertools import combinations
rdd.mapValues(lambda x: list(combinations(x, 2)))
```

In Scala, we can use the `combinations()` method in a similar way. But because it only ingests and outputs objects type `Seq`, we'll have to chain together a couple more methods to arrive at your expected format:

```scala
rdd.mapValues(_.toSeq.combinations(2).toArray.map{case Seq(x,y) => (x,y)})
```

Comment: Thanks! It helped a lot! ^-^